# How do I access the ModelState from an ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, modelstate

I'm building an `ActionFilter` to reuse some code for a simple spam block - basically what I do is that I have a `Html Helper` method that renders an input textbox and a hidden input, and in the ActionFilter I check whether the two values are the same or not. If not, I want to leverage the rest of my validation logic and add a `ModelStateError` to the `ModelState`, but how do I do that? How do I add a `ModelStateError` from whithin the `ActionFilter`?

UPDATE: Here's the code I'm trying with. When I test a controller action that has this attribute, `ModelState.IsValid` still returns `true` even though I don't pass any of the form values required:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var r = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
    if (r.Form["sixtimesnine"] != r.Form["fourtytwo"] || string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Form["sixtimesnine"]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Form["fourtytwo"]))
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("Spam", this.ErrorMessage);
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

This is the `ActionMethod`:

```
[ValidateAntiSpam(ErrorMessage = "Spambotar får inte.")]
public ActionResult Write(GuestbookPost postToCreate)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _posts.Add(postToCreate);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

I just noticed that if I set a breakpoint inside the `OnActionExecuting` method and hit "Debug tests", the breakpoint is never hit. Why?

Comment: The fact that your breakpoint is not being hit points to the solution why your filter doesn't work.

Other action filters you wrote do work?  Are you sure you haven't left out anything?

Comment: Well, I'm not that sure since the code is not running. But I can't figure out what I could have left out... I seem to have done everything described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx

Answer (score 99, accepted):

That would be by: 
`filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState`

Comment: I tried this, but it does not seem to work. I've updated my post with the code I have currently.

Comment: As this is actually the answer to the question I asked, I'll cred you for it. I've opened a new question with the "new" problem...

Comment: nowadays it is even easier, just `filterContext.ModelState`