# in MVC4 shows and error that I have to implement some Interface but I am already done it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, multilingual, interface-implementation

I am trying to create own filter attribute in order to support multilinguality.
The idea is simple. URL stands for language.

- *http://host.ext/**en**/rest_of_the_url* will open in English and
- *http://host.ext/**hy**/rest_of_the_url* will open in Armenian.

The problem is that at run it says that MultilingualActionFilterAttribute

Here is the error text "The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter."

Here I am using it as global filter.

```
namespace TIKSN.STOZE.WebApp
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new TIKSN.STOZE.Common.MultilingualActionFilterAttribute());
            filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am defining it.

```
namespace TIKSN.STOZE.Common
{
    public class MultilingualActionFilterAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string language = System.Convert.ToString(filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"]);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Requested language is '{0}'", language);
            language = Helper.PickUpSupportedLanguage(language);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Supported language is '{0}'", language);

            if (language == string.Empty)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent(new { language = Common.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguageCode });
            }

            language = Helper.TryToPickUpSupportedLanguage(language);

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That all looks OK. Is this a brand new MVC4 site or one upgraded from MVC3? It could be a dll version issue - have you tried deleting your temporary ASP.NET files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I updated to MVC 5, so I had to update *web.config* files too.
Look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).

Comment: Since the link is dead, could you please tell me what you had to do?

Comment: Link is not dead. Please check it again.

Answer (score 26):

if you are using web api then the problem may happen because of implementing wrong interface, as `IActionFilter` is defined in both `System.Web.Http.Filters` and `System.Web.Mvc` namespaces.

Comment: No, there are not any 'using'-s. I have implemented System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute class, which itself implements System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter interface.

Comment: Web API filters are registered using GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters. Check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1835666.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

This one works:

Please add your filter to the webApiconfig instead of filter config file.

From A. Murray:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518692/4853768